# Ads cannot show properly, activity_main.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

In LinearLayout, my adds cannot show up saying there is not enough space for ads, when I changed it to RelativeLayout ads can show up but, the buttons I keep at the top is gone. Please help me. And also, I would like to place my add at the bottom if possible. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:onClick="gotoPreviousImage"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="&lt;" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:onClick="setAsWallpaper"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="Set as Background" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:onClick="gotoNextImage"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text=">" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundPreview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:contentDescription="Preview of the wallpaper to choose"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/AdView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="Unit_ID"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to give weights like layout_weight for individual child component

Comment: how are you showing this ImageView? I guess this one has fill_parent for height and width. So try removing it for a momemnt and see if everything else works fine.

Comment: @vo12 Not working :( Still the same error 
" Not enough space to show ad. Needs 360x50 dp, but only has 360x0 dp."

Comment: Dude you have put vertical orientation put weights on First child linear layout ,imageview and on adview and make height 0px

Comment: @SeijiDinzuala give Imageview height wrap_parent

Comment: Giving wrap_content doesn't help either. @vo12 I can't understand you. >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Replace this code with your xml code and replay me  

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:onClick="gotoPreviousImage"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="&lt;" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:onClick="setAsWallpaper"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="Set as Background" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:onClick="gotoNextImage"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text=">" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backgroundPreview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:contentDescription="Preview of the wallpaper to choose"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />


    </LinearLayout>
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/AdView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="Unit_ID"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: Use framelayout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:onClick="gotoPreviousImage"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="&lt;" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:onClick="setAsWallpaper"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Set as Background" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:onClick="gotoNextImage"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text=">" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundPreview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="Preview of the wallpaper to choose"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/AdView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="Unit_ID" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Thank you, but still the three buttons are invisible or they're behind Imageview same as in RelativeLayout :(

Comment: looking fine in my case.. I edited answer to put gravity on first linear layout. Try with that

Comment: Lol. Still the same, any other ideas? :D

Comment: show how its looking now. Because in my case its looking fine and shw code also

Comment: I'm sorry for late reply, here is the picture http://i.imgur.com/mhfFUuy.png
I think we need to scale the pictures?